# I'm trying to make a console based battleship game but I don't know how to set the ships

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, console

```
int randRow = rand.nextInt(rows-4);
int randColumn = rand.nextInt(columns);
```

Here I check if my new ship doesn't interfere with my first ship. The entire array is filled with objects which contain a '.' char except for where the first ship is

```
if(field[randRow][randColumn].value == '.' &&
    field[randRow][randColumn+1].value == '.' &&
    field[randRow][randColumn+2].value == '.' &&
    field[randRow][randColumn+3].value == '.'){
        field[randRow][randColumn] = new Square('b');
        field[randRow+1][randColumn] = new Square('b');
        field[randRow+2][randColumn] = new Square('b');
        field[randRow+3][randColumn] = new Square('b');

} else{
```

If my new ship doesn't fit, I want to retry with different random values but I don't know how.

Comment: I see this is your first question.  Just for your future reference it is a good idea to add the logic alongnwith the code. Like the battleship takes four places. Also tangential to the question is  a suggestion. Make methods like `isLocationEmpty` and `placeBattleShip`. It will be easier to read the code then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you are not sure how to generate the random number again. Just use something like below

```
while(true) {
     //generate random number here
     if (can place battleship) {
          place battleship
          break //placed battleship so no need to retry. stop retrying
     }
     //else we will loop till we can place the battleship
}
```

Comment: @dandeman If this is what you were looking for then upvote/accept the answer. I hope you have taken the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @dandeman One last thing. Look and think about the comment that I left on the question. If your code is easy to read you will see things easier like this answer. Otherwise you will be looking at array and loops instead of actual logic.